# Cnverting JSON to Java Object using GSON

Tags: javascript, java, json, jakarta-ee, gson

Can you please let me know what went wrong in the below sample.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
private String age;
```

}

**JsontoJava.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class JsontoJava {

public static void main(String ar[]){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "{\"Employee\":[{\"name\":\"Test\", \"age\":\"12\"}]}";
    Employee staff = gson.fromJson(json, Employee.class);
    System.out.println("Name : "+staff.getName());
}
```

}

**Unfortunately getting the wrong output:**

Name :null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not right. Change to this.

```
{"name":"Test","age":"12"}
```

Comment: Great thanks... it works.. so we don't need to mention the class name in the JSON Object notation ??

Comment: No, we needn't . Just use the content.